# Why memory keeps increasing when you scroll in a List on Android

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I am watching the monitor on Android and I notice that the memory keeps increasing when you scroll down and up.
I am using an `Adaper`. It's supposed to reuse the views, but it seems that it doesn't work.

As you can see in the images below the memory starts at 9.94 MB and I could increase it at 25.82 MB just by scrolling down and up.

- [image: pic1] [image: pic2] [image: pic3] [image: pic4]

You can see the code that I use.

```
public class ListMainFragment
            extends Fragment
            implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Earthquake>> {

    public ListMainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View viewRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mainlist, container, false);

        final ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquake =
            (ArrayList<Earthquake>) new EarthquakeController(new EarthquakesJson()).getListOfEarthquakes();

        listView = (ListView)viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        EarthquakeAdapter noteAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(getActivity(), earthquake);
        listView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            //final String mensaje = notas.get(position).getMag();
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(earthquake.get(0).getMapURL()));
                Log.w("ListView", "Se despliega la siguente URL " + earthquake.get(0).getMapURL());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return viewRoot;
    }
}
```

The `Adapter`:

```
public class EarthquakeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <Earthquake> {

    public EarthquakeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Earthquake> notas) {
        super(context, 0, notas);
    }

    private static final String LOCATION_SEPARATOR = " of";
    View view;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        /*if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        */
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
            Log.w("AppList", "converView es null");
        }

        Earthquake note = getItem(position);

        Date dateObject = new Date(note.getTimeInMilliseconds());
        TextView locationOffset = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItem_tv_locationOffset);
        TextView place = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItem_tv_place);
        TextView date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lisItem_tv_date);
        TextView time = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lisItem_tv_time);
        TextView mag = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItem_tv_mag);

        GradientDrawable magnitudCicle = (GradientDrawable) mag.getBackground();
        magnitudCicle.setColor(getMagnitudColor(note.getMag()));
        String str_locationOffset, str_place;

        if (note.getPlace().contains(LOCATION_SEPARATOR)) {
            String [] locations = note.getPlace().split(LOCATION_SEPARATOR);
            str_locationOffset = locations[0];
            str_place = locations[1];
        }
        else {
            str_place = note.getPlace();
            str_locationOffset = getContext().getString(R.string.near_the);
        }

        mag.setText( new DecimalFormat("0.0").format(note.getMag()));
        date.setText(formatDate(dateObject));
        place.setText(str_place);
        time.setText(formatTime(dateObject));
        locationOffset.setText(str_locationOffset);

        /* final String  mensaje = title.getText().toString();
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),mensaje,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });*/

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't implementing the ViewHolder method like you should. `findViewById` can be an intense process, and getting the GradientDrawable each time probably pushes the drawable to the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Recycler View** for better performance.

From: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: This should be a comment.